# How to select owner while creating Github repository using terraform

Tags: github, terraform, github-api

I can create Github repository in an organisation as well as under my personal namespace.
I'm trying to create repository under org with terraform https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs/resources/repository

[image]

But it creates the repository under my personal namespace. The token I am using is authorized to create repository under the org. How do I specify the owner/org for the repo?

Putting name as `org/repoName` does not seem to work.

```
resource "github_repository" "new-repo" {
  name        = "org/sos-repo"
  private     = true

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the organisation is considered the [owner input on the provider configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs#owner).

This setting used to be called "organization".

You can specify it in the provider configuration block or you can use an environment variable `GITHUB_OWNER`.

e.g.

```
provider "github" {
  owner = "my-org"

  app_auth {
    id              = var.app_id              # or `GITHUB_APP_ID`
    installation_id = var.app_installation_id # or `GITHUB_APP_INSTALLATION_ID`
    pem_file        = var.app_pem_file        # or `GITHUB_APP_PEM_FILE`
  }
}

resource "github_membership" "membership_for_user_x" {
  # ...
}

resource "github_repository" "example" {
  name        = "example"
  description = "My awesome codebase"

  visibility = "public"
}
```